# Does every cover has a countable subcover?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

When dealing with outer measure, I came up with this problem when extending a set function $\rho:\mathcal{C}\to [0,\infty]$ with $X=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ and $\rho(\varnothing)=0$ to an outer measure by defining
$$
\rho^{*}(E):=\inf\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \rho(C_i): C_i\in\mathcal{C} \text{ and } E\subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i \right\}.
$$

The family $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $2^X$ that contains $\varnothing$.

It seems fine but the cover for $X$ is an arbitrary cover. Is there any theorem to guarantee that we can always find a countable cover for any subset $E\in 2^X$?

Comment: What do you know about $\mathcal C$?  If empty set is the only set in it then there is no cover for $E=X$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I update the description. $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $2^X$ that contains $\varnothing$.

Comment: Well, I  already gave a counter-example. But you can define the infimum of the empty set as $+\infty$.

Comment: If $X$ is an uncountable set, then the collection of all one-element subsets of $X$ is a cover for $X$ that has no ountable subcover.

Comment: @bof This is a good answer to the question, could you write it up as such?

Comment: It could be that $E$ has no countable cover by elements of $\mathcal C$.  Then we take $\rho^*(E) = \inf\varnothing = +\infty$.  This "Method I" construction still makes sense to define an outer measure $\rho^*$.